# Python: Join consecutive lines if separated by backslash and remove backslash also

Tags: python

I have got a file containing shell commands. Each command may be split across multiple lines (using backslash at end):
e.g.

```
  cmd1 -opt1 \  
    -opt2 val2  \  
    -opt3 val3 val4
```

I want to join consecutive lines if separated by backslash at end. i also want to remove backslash after joining.

The problem is similar to:
Input:
['abc', 'def \\', 'ghi \\', 'jkl' , 'yyy \\', 'zzz']
output:
['abc', 'def ghi jkl', 'yyy zzz']

is looping through the list only solution ?

```
with open("cmd", "r") as fp:
    cmd = ""
    cont = False
    list = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if line.endswith('\\'):
            line = line[:-1]
            if cont:
                cmd = cmd + line
                continue
            if cmd:
                list.append(cmd)
            cmd = line
            cont = True
        else:
            if cont:
                cmd = cmd + line
                if cmd:
                    list.append(cmd)
                cmd = ""
                continue
            cont = False
    print(list)
```

Comment: You can try creating a dictionary of commands, and then do the joining only for commands that has multiple parts. So your dict would look like this: `{'command1':['part1 \', 'part2 \', 'part3 \'], 'command2':['the_only_part']}.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cmd = ['abc', 'def \\\', 'ghi \\\', 'jkl' , 'yyy \\\', 'zzz']

res = "\n".join(cmd).replace("\\\\\n", "").splitlines()

print(res)

=> ['abc', 'def ghi jkl', 'yyy zzz']
```

Comment: If you read from file (can be CR/LF): res = open(file, "r").read().replace("\\\n", "").splitlines()

Answer (score 1):

> is looping through the list only solution ?

You will have to assess each line for a concatenation indicator and append the next line. Yes, you'll have to loop through.

Here's a function to do it using a generator so the whole input doesn't need to be in memory.

```
>>> sample = ['abc', 'def \\', 'ghi \\', 'jkl' , 'yyy \\', 'zzz']
>>>
>>> def join_lines(sequence):
...   i = iter(sequence)
...   buff = ''
...   try:
...     while True:
...       line = i.next()
...       if line.endswith('\\'):
...         line = line[:-1]
...         buff += line
...       else:
...         if buff:
...           buff += line
...           yield buff
...           buff = ''
...         else:
...           yield line
...   except StopIteration:
...     if buff:
...       yield buff
...
>>> print sample
['abc', 'def \\', 'ghi \\', 'jkl', 'yyy \\', 'zzz']
>>> print list(join_lines(sample))
['abc', 'def ghi jkl', 'yyy zzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be way to join lines and iterate over such a file:

```
with open("cmd", "r") as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    lines = data.replace("\\\n", "").splitlines()
    lines = [ x + "\n" for x in lines ]
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```